# Mongoose: How to query nested document and return String result?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Did a query `Product.findOne({'variation.sku': req.params.productVariationSKU },{'_id': 0, 'variation.price' :1})` to find the price of a product variation.

But result returned price of all product variations. Need help to find where went wrong!

Below is product schema:

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    productId: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Product ID is required'],
        unique: true
    },
    sku: String,
    category: [String],
    language: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        maxlength: 2,
        required: [true, 'Language code required'],
        index: true,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Product name is required']
    },
    descLong: String,
    descShort: String,
    mainImageURL: String,
    galleryImageURL: [String],
    variation: [{
        sku: String,
        option: [{
            label: String,
            value: String,
        }],
        inventory: [{
            name: String,
            quantity: Number,
            country: String
        }],
        inStock: Boolean,
        price: mongoose.Types.Decimal128
    }],
    attribute: [{
        label: String,
        value: [String]
    }],
    inStock: Boolean,
    currencySymbol: String,
    slug: String,
    metaTitle: String,
    metaDescription: String,
    relatedAccessory: [Number],
    htmlContentBefore: String,
    htmlContentAfter: String
});
```

Below is product object from Postman:

```
{
    "category": [],
    "galleryImageURL": [
        "TEST.png"
    ],
    "relatedAccessory": [],
    "_id": "5feae4418d686300176dfbbd",
    "productId": 1,
    "language": "en",
    "name": "TEST PRODUCT",
    "descLong": "<p><strong>This is a long description</strong></p>",
    "descShort": "Short Description",
    "mainImageURL": "TEST.png",
    "variation": [
        {
            "option": [
                {
                    "_id": "5feae4418d686300176dfbbf",
                    "label": "Color",
                    "value": "Black"
                }
            ],
            "inventory": [],
            "_id": "5feae4418d686300176dfbbe",
            "sku": "P-1",
            "inStock": true,
            "price": "45"
        },
        {
            "option": [
                {
                    "_id": "5feae4418d686300176dfbc1",
                    "label": "Color",
                    "value": "White"
                }
            ],
            "inventory": [],
            "_id": "5feae4418d686300176dfbc0",
            "sku": "P-2",
            "inStock": true,
            "price": "45"
        }
    ],
    "attribute": [
        {
            "value": [
                "Black",
                "White"
            ],
            "_id": "5feae4418d686300176dfbc2",
            "label": "Color"
        }
    ],
    "currencySymbol": "£",
    "slug": "test",
    "metaTitle": "testmeta",
    "metaDescription": "This is meta description",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Below is API function:

```
app.get('/API/Product/GetProductVariationPrice/:productVariationSKU', async(req, res) => {
  try{
    res.send(await Product.findOne({'variation.sku': req.params.productVariationSKU },{'_id': 0, variation :1}));
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

Returned result from Postman:

```
{
    "variation": [
        {
            "price": "45"
        },
        {
            "price": "45"
        }
    ]
}
```

Question: How can I get just "45" of variation SKU "P-1"? As the result currently returns the price of variation 'P-2' as well which is not wanted. SKU should be based on the param passed to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it will return array of object when we project specific field from array of object,

[Starting in MongoDB 4.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection), as part of making `find` projection consistent with aggregation’s `$project` stage,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `variation` array, check condition if `sku` match then it will return `price`

```
await Product.findOne(
{ "variation.sku": req.params.productVariationSKU },
{
  "_id": 0,
  variation: {
    $reduce: {
      input: "$variation",
      initialValue: 0,
      in: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$$this.sku", req.params.productVariationSKU] },
          "$$this.price",
          "$$value"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yufa2FfRXDf)

---

MongoDB 4.4 or below versions try `aggregate()`,

```
let p = Product.aggregate();
p.match({ "variation.sku": req.params.productVariationSKU });
p.project({
    _id: 0,
    variation: {
        $reduce: {
            input: "$variation",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: {
                $cond: [
                    { $eq: ["$$this.sku", req.params.productVariationSKU] },
                    "$$this.price",
                    "$$value"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
});
res.send(await p.exec());
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gDjklaotAQ4)

Comment: Hi @turivishal, any chance you could show the way using Mongoose? As I can't couldn't find the Mongoose equivalent of $reduce.

Comment: this is exact query you can use in mongoose. is there any issues are you getting? $reduce is a part of projection so we have used in projection.

Comment: It shows this in Postman
`{
    "operationTime": "6919704166583500802",
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "Unsupported projection option: variation: { $reduce: { input: \"$variation\", initialValue: 0, in: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ \"$$this.sku\", \"PNS-0001\" ] }, \"$$this.price\", \"$$value\" ] } } }",
    "code": 2,
    "codeName": "BadValue",
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": "6919704166583500802",
        "signature": {
            "hash": "8CyP1nN8SgQio3U8sTmeDsJt9oA=",
            "keyId": "6868417738763665412"
        }
    },
    "name": "MongoError"
}`

Comment: I have mentioned it is starting from mongodb 4.4, what is your mongodb version? if its lower then try aggregation.

Comment: It results in the same error

`{
    "operationTime": "6919709677026541574",
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "Unsupported projection option: variation: { $reduce: { input: \"$variation\", initialValue: 0, in: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ \"$$this.sku\", \"PNS-0001\" ] }, \"$$this.price\", \"$$value\" ] } } }",
    "code": 2,
    "codeName": "BadValue",
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": "6919709677026541574",
        "signature": {
            "hash": "xA3+EAJfL0LSek/OK4RIfoK8Nuk=",
            "keyId": "6868417738763665412"
        }
    },
    "name": "MongoError"
}`

Comment: MongoDB version is 4.2

Comment: There are something wrong in projection, can you add new code with this query in question, that you are getting this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227569/discussion-between-ugene-and-turivishal).

Comment: Product.aggregate([
      { $match: { "variation.sku": req.params.productVariationSKU } },
      {
        $project: {
          "_id": 0,
          variation: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$variation",
              initialValue: 0,
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this.sku", req.params.productVariationSKU] },
                  "$$this.price",
                  "$$value"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ])

Comment: I have updated the answer, i am not sure but give it try.

Comment: Hi @turivishal, YOU ARE MY SAVIOUR!! Thanks so much! Your solution worked!